# async await not working in composable function vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In my project I have a function for downloading the files. When click the button the function `onDownload` will be called:

```
import {useOnDownload} from "../../use/useOnDownload"

setup() {

    ...

    const loading = ref(null)
    onDownload = (id) => {
        loading.value = id
        await useOnDownload(id)
        loading.value = null
    }
    
    return {loading, onDownload}
}
```

I refactored the code for api in a file `useOnDownload.js` call because the same code is used in another components as well.

```
export async function useOnDownload(id) {
    // make api call to server with axios
}
```

What I did wrong? I need to wait for the function useOnDownload ... in order the loader to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solved another way without async and await...

I passed the reference object loader to the function parameter (as optional) and handle from there...

```
export function useOnDownload(id, loader) {
   if(loader !== undefined) {
     loader.value = id
   }
   axios.post('/api/download', {id: id}, {
      responseType: 'blob'
   }).then(response => {
     // handle the response
     ...
     if(loader !== undefined) {
       loader.value = null
     }
   }).catch(error => {
     // handle the error
     ...
     if(loader !== undefined) {
       loader.value = null
     }
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to make async composable functions with async await syntax

```
export default function useOnDownload() {
  const isLoading = ref(true);

  const onDownload = async () => {
    isLoading.value = true;
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('/api/download', {id: id}, 
     {responseType: 'blob'})
        // handle the response

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  };
   // invoke the function
  onDownload();

  return { // return your reactive data here };
}


import useOnDownload from "../../use/useOnDownload"
// no await in setup script or function 
const { reactiveDataReturned } = useOnDownload();
```

Read more [here](https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/coding-better-composables-5-of-5/)

Answer (score 0):

onDownload must be async in order to use await within it

Answer (score 0):

You are using the await keyword in your onDownlaod function, but the function is not asynchronous. Here's how you should update it.

```
   // next line important
   onDownload = async(id) => {
    loading.value = id
    await useOnDownload(id)
    loading.value = null
}
```

Comment: not working... the loading is changing so fast.... that means it does not wait for the function to run (to get the server response success or failed). It moves instant from `loading.value = id` to `loading.value = null`

Comment: @calin24 You cannot wait for an asynchronous operation in JavaScript. It's simply not possible.